# Registering to all browser interaction events ember

Tags: ember.js

I am building a cordova application in emberjs, and I would like the phone to vibrate every time a button is clicked. currently i am thinking of hooking into the core event pane that recives the click from the browser and finds the nearest action handler

i am not sure where to find this file, and I am happy to hear other suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about hooking into Ember, but there is a way that's supported right out of the box. Simply define a click handler on the `window` that will catch all bubbled events.

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({

    setup: function() {
        $(window).off('click.vibrate').on('click.vibrate', function(e) {
            vibrate();
        });
    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    teardown: function() {
        $(window).off('click.vibrate');
    }.on('willDestroyElement')

});
```

Now, any click events that bubble to the window will vibrate the phone. However, if you want to prevent bubbling, but still have the phone vibrate, then I'm afraid this solution won't work for you.